# How to pass php variable through jQuery and back to php using form without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use a lightbox popup for several things, especially for people to leave feedback on work in progress, to approve/reject a job and so on.

Now I want to re-use this code for something that looks simple but I can't get it to work.

The first part of the code below triggers a jQuery script and passes on the variable `$order_id1`, which I need later on:

```
<button class="inner-preview" onclick="previewOrder('<?php echo $order_id1 ?>');" title="Preview the work">P</button>
```

This is the jQuery script that triggers the lightbox to popup, does it's job as well (eg. the lightbox pops up):

```
<script>
function previewOrder(order_id1)
{
    jQuery('#preview_content').val(order_id1);
    jQuery('.lightBoxWrapper3').fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

Now it gets tricky, as I want to call some things from the database using the variable `$order_id1` as the ID to find it in the database.

```
<div class="lightBoxWrapper3" style="display: none; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; background-color: gray;">
    <div class="lightBoxContentArea3" style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <p style="font-size:24px;margin:10px 0 20px 0;color:#6D7678;">Preview the work:</p>
        <a class="closedPopup3" href="javascript:jQuery('.lightBoxWrapper3').fadeOut();">X</a>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="order_id1" id="preview_content" value="">
            <?php 
                    $getwork=getOrder(['order_id1']);
                    echo "<h2>".$getwork['title']."</h2>";
                    echo $getwork['content'];
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in short I want to use which was initially send as `$order_id1` and which jQuery turned into `order_id1` to be used in my `getOrder()` function without receiving an undefined index error message as it's already defined way earlier in the code over here:

```
            <div class="inner-bottom2">
                <?php foreach($orders as $approve_order) {
                    $order_id1=$approve_order['id'];
                    $status1=$approve_order['status'];
                    $approve1=$approve_order['approve'];
                    $title1=$approve_order['project_title'];
                    $writer_id1=$approve_order['writer_id'];
                    $name1=get_userdata($writer_id1);
                    if ($status1==1 && $approve1==0) { ?>
                    <ul>
                        <div class="inner-title"><?php echo wordwrap(substr($title1,0,40)); ?></div>
                        <div class="inner-id">ID: <?php echo $order_id1; ?></div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <div class="inner-user2">By: <?php echo $name1->user_login; ?></div>
                        <button class="inner-reject" onclick="rejectOrder('<?php echo $order_id1 ?>');" title="Request a revision">R</a>
                        <button class="inner-approve" onclick="approveOrder('<?php echo $order_id1 ?>');" title="Approve the work">A</button>
                        <button class="inner-preview" onclick="previewOrder('<?php echo $order_id1 ?>');" title="Preview the work">P</button>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </ul>
                    <?php }
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The `getOrder` function on itself works fine, if I wouldn't get this undefined index issue cause it gets passed through jQuery.

In short I just want to pass those values from a specific `foreach` row to this lightbox thing and the only way to get there is through jQuery as I don't want the page to refresh, I can easily echo content and title in the first part of the code but that doesn't make it show up in the lightbox. Some have said use colorbox instead but it's not compatible with my theme for whatever reason and when I install the colorbox plugin all jQuery functions seaze working alltogether so I want to get it done with this lightbox, which works perfectly fine for my other goals like sending messages and such.

Comment: I suggest you check out `AJAX`. This will let you pass data between Javascript (jQuery) and PHP. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: PHP is rendered on the server, and then sent to the user's browser.  You can't use PHP once the page is rendered and in the browser, that's JavaScript's realm.  See the comment above about `AJAX`, jQuery makes AJAX very easy.  You'll need to make a separate PHP page to accept and return values from AJAX based on your needs, or look for a certain input at the beginning of that PHP file, and return the values without running the rest of the page script.  Good luck!

Comment: Right now I use a collapse script instead using Toggle, so the values content and title from the database are already being echo'ed, just hidden. Can't I get that to display in the lightbox somehow?

Comment: I really have no clue whatsoever about AJAX and I just want those 2 values echo'ed in the lightbox, that are in fact already echo'ed in the `foreach` section but hidden, I edited out that code to avoid distractions.

Comment: AJAX is just a way for the client to make requests to the server (and sometimes receive a response).  But as your code stands now, the server writes the page, mails it, and then fucks off to the Bahamas for a rum and coke: it did its job. It has no idea who it sent that to, it doesn't care.  You want it to come home and do some more work?  AJAX-mail it a postcard.